# @Transactional do not work in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-boot

I'm looking to use @Transactional in spring boot, but after several attempts i cannot get the transaction working despite having an exception inside to rollback, so i'm missing somthing ?

**AppConfig.java**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.geopro" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.geopro.repositories" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.geopro.entities" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
         HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean factory = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
         factory.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
         return factory;
    }
}
```

**Metier.java**

```
@Service("metier")
@Aspect
public class Metier {


    @Transactional(readOnly = false , rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void saveUpload(UploadData post) throws Exception {
        try {
            post.ADDEDDATA.savesync();
            post.UPDATEDDATA.savesync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
               throw e ;
        }

    }
```

Comment: "despite having an exception inside to rollback" - of course the transaction will roll back if an exception has occurred

Comment: in my case it do not rollback.

Comment: There's not much to go on, perhaps you could share a project that demonstrates the problem. Since your `Metier` service doesn't implement an interface I wonder if you need `@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)`?

Comment: @PhilWebb your trick is working perfectly, you have saved me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause for my problem Transactions not working is mixing AspectJ advices and Transactions in the same class, so this option `@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)` Forces the Transactions to work but, disables AspectJ advices even if you place them in a dedicated class.

So the best solution for this problem is put AspectJ advices in a dedicated Class, so Transactions and AspectJ advices will work like expected.